# How to emit event for socket io from another place, not from main app initializer script?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

How to export and emit even for socket io from different scripts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- By this method it is only convenient to emit an event
- You can initialize a class like this
- **ServerMainFile**

```
const { Server }= require('socket.io')

class socketioserver{
   constructor(){
       this.io=new Server(3000,{cors: {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",methods: ["GET", "POST", "OPTIONS"]},});
       this.io.on('connection',socket=>{
           console.log(socket.id)
       })
   }
   emit(eventName,data,id){
       if(id) return this.io.to(id).emit(eventName,data)
       this.io.emit(eventName,data)
   }
   on(eventName){
       return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
           this.io.on('connection',(socket)=>{
               socket.on(eventName,(data)=>{
                   resolve(data)
               })
           })
       })
   }
   io
}

const ioServer=new socketioserver()
ioServer.emit('apple','')
```

- the following class can be initialized any where and then imported into any other files for emitting events to the same server
- **ClientSideBrowserJavascript**

```
const socket = io("http://localhost:3000")
  socket.on('connect', () => {
   socket.on('apple', (data) => {
   console.log(data)
  })
```